# Python 2.7.12 Runtime error. Application requests Runtime to terminate in unusual way

Tags: python, matplotlib

When running the code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
```

I get the error

[image]

How can I stop this message from appearing?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the error? (I wouldn't ordinarily ask for an image, but this doesn't sound copy-pasteable.)

Comment: Error occurs when I close the Python Shell or if I attempt to run the Module twice.

Comment: I think you need to track down the problem yourself by testing a couple of things. In how far is this specific to this code or do other codes produce the same error? Does it also occur when not clearing the figure at the end? Is is specific to using any of the imports (not using math, not using mplot3d)?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen similar errors occurring in a program due to problems of compatibility of a new program with an old graphics driver. Right-click in the pythonw.exe and check the compatibility mode, see if there is something different checked there, such as "run in 256 colors" or "run in compatibility mode". Anything should be unchecked, so that you run the most recent version of the drivers. You might also try to reinstall your python distribution or the matplotlib library. Try using `pip install --upgrade matplotlib`.